# How to auto connect with Soket.io

Tags: socket.io

I'm creating a webapp that support offline mode using AppCache.

When I'm online, it connect fine. If the connection is dropped and regain, it reconnect correctly.

My problem is when I'm opening my webapp when disconnected and then a connect to the internet, Socket.IO doesn't connect. It just doesn't try to connect.

I analysed a little bit the code, and it seen that it need a first valid connection in order to try to reconnect. If the first connection fail, it will permanently fail.

Is there something I miss?

Answer (score 0):

So what stops you to have a global variable `isConnectionStartedOnce`, initialize it on the first successful connection. And on re connection event if it is initiaziled - reconnect, otherwise connect from scratch.